# How to use .htaccess to allow a file access images under the same directory, but deny other people from seeing images directly?

Tags: html, .htaccess

I have a file called `display.html` that I would like to use to show images. However, I do not want to let other people directly access the images by typing the images' names in the URL. Therefore, I use `.htaccess` to deny access but somehow it denied `display.html` as well. I have my code for `.htaccess` below:

```
# Prevent direct access to images
Options -Indexes

# Allow display.html to access images
<Files "display.html">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Files>

# Allow access to images for display.html only
<FilesMatch "\.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$">
    Order deny,allow
    Deny from all
    <Files "display.html">
        Order allow,deny
        Allow from all
    </Files>
</FilesMatch>
```

In this code, shouldn't it allow `display.html` access the all the other jpg and jpeg files? But it showed 403 error when trying to load the images. How can I modify the .htaccess file to make it work? Thank you ahead for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have a file called `display.html` that I would like to use to show images.

Presumably in this HTML file you are simply embedding images using the `img` element? In which case you can't simply block these images in `.htaccess`, which is blocking all HTTP requests to these images.

The problem is not that `display.html` itself is being blocked, but the images that are embedded in `display.html` are being blocked.

The only option you have is to check the `Referer` (one "r") HTTP request header when these images are requested. The `Referer` *should****** contain the URL from which the image is being requested.

For example, using mod_rewrite in `.htaccess`:

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com/display\.html$
RewriteRule \.(jpe?g|png|gif)$ - [F]
```

The above blocks (403 Forbidden) any request for the stated image extensions where the HTTP `Referer` header is *not* `https://www.example.com/display.html`. This is basically a form of "hotlink protection".

*****HOWEVER, this is not necessarily reliable. The `Referer` header is sent by the user/browser. It's possible the user has suppressed the sending of `Referer` headers (in interests of "security"), so the images will not be displayed for these users. Consequently, the `Referer` header can also be faked (so the images could still be downloaded from an external source, if that is a concern).

---

> ```
> # Allow display.html to access images
> <Files "display.html">
>     Order allow,deny
>     Allow from all
> </Files>
> ```

This allows access to `display.html` itself. But that's not the problem. `display.html` is already accessible. The problem is that you are blocking all access to your images, regardless of where they are being accessed "from". "from" is the "referrer" (represented by the `Referer` HTTP request header).

Comment: This is exactly what I need!! No wonder I couldn't find the solution since I was not aware of the actual cause of the problem. Thank you for pointing it out and sharing the answer!